# sudo does not prompt for password and reports 3 incorrect password attempts

Tags: centos, sudo

User `smithj` is listed in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
smithj ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

`smithj` logs into the system via putty. He attempts to `sudo` but gets this:

```
sudo adduser jonesjp
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

He is never prompted for his password. This is on CentOS 6.

This used to work, but another admin made some unknown changes that resulted in this and he is not available.

Comment: What does `/var/log/secure` says?

Comment: check SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable

Comment: /var/log/secure: Oct  4 14:50:58 CentBOx sudo: smithj : 3 incorrect password attempts ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/smithj ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/adduser jonesjp

Comment: SUDO_ASKPASS is not set, but SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass

Comment: /etc/sudo.conf is showing as having been changed recently. Is there something in there that I should be looking for?

Comment: check for 'Path askpass'

Comment: Was /etc/pam.d/sudo changed?

Comment: No, /etc/pam.d/sudo has not been changed.

Comment: What if you use a gui/X session or mobaxterm from windows? Also try sudo -D 9 -i

Comment: sudo -D 9 -i gives the same response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some things to check:

Have the user run `sudo -l`.  This just asks sudo to tell you what permissions you have.  If you can't manage this, there's a fundamental issue authenticating that's probably separate from sudo itself.

Compare `/etc/pam.d/sudo` with other functional systems (or backups).

Compare `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` with other functional systems (or backups).  Subtle changes to this system can introduce gnarly troubleshooting problems.

Look at `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and see if the `pam_access.so` module is in use.  If so, you'll want to check whether `smithj` is allowed in `/etc/security/access.conf` (unless another file is specified by the PAM module).  One potentially tricky problem is if the account is allowed access from a remote IP, but not locally; this ends up allowing a remote log in, but local actions like cron jobs and sudo authentications fail.

Is `smithj` logging in via password?  Or via keys?  Make sure they can log in with a password to help narrow the problem.  If they can't successfully use their password anywhere, start looking at changes against `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and any config files associated with the directory you're using (perhaps none, perhaps LDAP, NIS, AD).

If you have a caching daemon running, perhaps `nscd` or `sssd`, restart the daemon (`sudo service nscd restart`).  These daemons are notorious for having problems.

Comment: 'sudo -l' produces:
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Comment: He is logging in via putty with a password

Comment: Is pam_access at play?

Comment: The only references to pam_access are in /etc/pam.d/atd and /etc/pam.d/crond which have not changed

Comment: Solved. The following two lines had been added to /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:

`auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900`
`auth required pam_faillock.so authsucc deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900`

Comment: @PaulCroarkin did removing these two lines work for you?  I commented them out and still have the same problem.

Comment: We use “pam_faillock.so” so we were getting this error when the account has a “faillock” entry.  The fix was to delete the ‘/var/log/faillock/${ACCOUNT}’ file.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on a RH Like custom system, the file /etc/pam.d/sudo didn't exists.

I just link it to /etc/pam.d/system-auth and it works:

```
root@fws1:~ # ln -s /etc/pam.d/system-auth /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

Comment: For me the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file did exit but just did not work for some reason. I moved it and created the symbolic link like you show and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check your `/etc/pam.conf` file.  to fix my issues I had to add

```
#############################
# SUDO service
#############################
sudo   auth       required        pam_authtok_get.so
sudo   auth       required        pam_dhkeys.so
sudo   auth       sufficient      pam_unix_auth.so
sudo   auth       required        pam_login_auth.so
sudo   account    required        pam_roles.so
sudo   account    required        pam_projects.so
sudo   account    required        pam_unix_account.so
sudo   account    required        pam_login_auth.so
```

Comment: there should be a line break before every sodo command

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file for `sudoers: files` and then check `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` for the user account.

I had LDAP configured and the user did not exist in local files hence the error as the server was looking in LDAP for authentication.

Sudo and LDAP configuration is an entirely different topic.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem compiling sudo for Linux from scratch 7.9. Having pam not properly installed, I had to recompile sudo --without-pam. So I solved the problem, it is surely in security.